# Running python file, which creates a JSON file, from js ajax call

Tags: javascript, python, json, ajax

I have a question about how to run a python file from a javascript ajax call.

Im using a python function using beautifulsoap framework to webscrape some data from a website. Im storing the data I need in a json file, my python function works really well if I run it from Windows console, for example.

The problem is that I want to receive this data from an ajax function in a chrome extension app. My plan is reading json file from javascript function, but python file is not being executed, so js function always receives the same json file and data is not being refreshed.

I have tried to know what is the response from python file, and js function recieves the whole python code in a string...

I dont want to pass any data from python to javascript, I only want to refresh json file with python function calling from the ajax function.

I attached python and js code.

**Python Code:**

```
import json
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request


url = 'http://www.website...'
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)'
values = {'name': 'Michael Foord',
      'location': 'Northampton',
      'language': 'Python' }
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data = data.encode('ascii')
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data, headers)
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
    the_page = response.read()

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(the_page, 'lxml')

for ulElement in soup.find_all('ul', class_='post-list'):
    for liElement in ulElement.find_all('li', class_='post-list-item'):
        dvDescription = liElement.find('div', class_='share-socials')
        aElementImage = liElement.find('a', class_='post-thumb-link')
        imgElementImage = aElementImage.find('img', class_='post-thumb')
        for h4Element in liElement.find_all('h4'):
            ThrasherTitles.append(h4Element.text)
            aElement = h4Element.find('a')
            data['videos'].append({
                'id': VideoCount,
                'title': h4Element.text,
                'url': aElement['href'],
                'description': dvDescription['data-text'],
                'imageurl': imgElementImage['src']
            })
            VideoCount += 1


with open('Sources/videosdata.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

**Javascript Code:**

```
function RefreshJSONFile(){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/main.py",
    success: function(data){
        
    }
  }).done(function(o) {
```

(js function is executed after we click a button)

Can anyone help me, please? Thanks everyone!

Comment: Please add more details. What web server are you using. You cannot run python just from browser, however web server can execute it and return HTTP response

Comment: Im not using a web server, I just tried to create chrome extension in full javascript, and python function to webscrap the website. Maybe I am trying something imposible or maybe there is another better solution to do the same

Comment: You cannot run python from browser extension directly without webserver, however you can do all required parsing in javascript using XPath, which works pretty similar to what you do.